# Logstash filter query with if else

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-filter

I am facing issues with Logstash filters:
I want to put a condition like following:

```
filter {
       if [SPCI] == 79 {
            mutate {
                 replace => { "RSRP79" => "%{SRSRP}" }
                 replace => { "RSRQ79" => "%{SRSRQ}" }
                   }
       }
```

My dataset looks like:

```
{
  "took": 29,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 22656,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "processed.radiosignal",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "v_FJQnYBEKhQVcwaCsCy",
        "_version": 26,
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "ElapsedRT": 0,
          "Alt": 0,
          "Row": 0,
          "RSRP116": "0",
          "NRSRP": -103,
          "@version": "1",
          "Handover": 0,
          "Time": "2020.12.08-11.34.49.14",
          "NRSRQ": -13,
          "SPCI": 79,
          "SRSRP": -100,
          "@timestamp": "2020-12-15T17:31:29.080Z",
          "SRSRQ": -11,
          "RSRP79": "0",
          "NPLMN": "nullnull",
          "NPCI": 116,
          "RSRQ116": "0",
          "Lat": 0,
          "Long": 0,
          "RSRQ79": "0"
        },
        "fields": {
          "@timestamp": [
            "2020-12-15T17:31:29.080Z"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1608053489080
        ]
      }
```

The query is not performing as expected and `if SRSRP == 79` is failing.
I am quite new to ELK and could not understand where is the issue.
Just to clarify, I am creating `RSRP79` and `RSRQ79` fields using alter plugin in previous step and it is working fine.

Comment: Is it possible that [SPCI] is a string in logstash and getting converted to an integer when it is indexed? If that is the case then `if [SPCI] == "79"` would work.

Comment: Not really, SPCI is a number when I check in Kibana. Although this suggestion did not work. I am not sure if I am accessing the field correctly.

Comment: Whether [SPCI] is a number in kibana (which it would be, since it is clearly a number in elasticsearch) and whether it is a number in logstash are unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for your response. On checking it closely again, I found an extra space in the `[ SPCI ]` due to which the error was occuring. It works now with the space removed `[SPCI]`